# javascript recursion null TypeError in body of a while loop that's not expected to be executed

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the newbie question.

I did some experiments and tried to implement a walkTheDOM function differently. This is what I wrote and I had an problem:

```
function walkTheDOM(root) {
    console.log(root);
    node = root.firstElementChild;
    while (node) {
        console.log('hey')
        walkTheDOM(node);
        console.log('hey2');
        node = node.nextElementSibling;
    }
}

walkTheDOM(document.body);
```

I ran this on a [twitter job posting page](https://careers.twitter.com/en/work-for-twitter/201901/data-science-manager-platform-manipulation0.html):

```
Script snippet %232:2 <body class=​"page job-posting-page " data-analytics-page=​"careers" data-analytics-section=​"work-for-twitter" data-analytics-component=​"201901/​data-science-manager-platform-manipulation0" data-analytics-element=​"page" style=​"border:​ 1px solid red;​">​…​</body>​
Script snippet %232:5 hey
Script snippet %232:2 <div id=​"page-wrapper">​…​</div>​
Script snippet %232:5 hey
Script snippet %232:2 <div id=​"loader-container">​…​</div>​
Script snippet %232:5 hey
Script snippet %232:2 <div id=​"loader" class>​</div>​
Script snippet %232:7 hey2
Script snippet %232:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of null
    at walkTheDOM (VM51636 Script snippet %232:8)
    at walkTheDOM (VM51636 Script snippet %232:6)
    at walkTheDOM (VM51636 Script snippet %232:6)
    at VM51636 Script snippet %232:12
```

I don't understand how in the last recursive call, 'hey' is not printed and 'hey2' is printed? I checked that node should be null there, and the while loop isn't supposed to run at all.

For reference, this is the walkTheDOM function that had no problem and that I want to change. I wanted to do something to the root node after the recursive calls to child nodes. If there is another way to do this, it's also appreciated!

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

// Example usage: Process all Text nodes on the page
walkTheDOM(document.body, function (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // Is it a Text node?
        var text = node.data.trim();
        if (text.length > 0) { // Does it have non white-space text content?
            // process text
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems to be fine. The problem is that you've declared `node` as a global variable, that's why when you recursively call `walkTheDOM`, `node` gets reassigned and becomes `null`. All you need is to add `let` before `node`:

```js
function walkTheDOM(root) {
    console.log(root);
    let node = root.firstElementChild;
    while (node) {
        console.log('hey')
        walkTheDOM(node);
        console.log('hey2');
        node = node.nextElementSibling;
    }
}

walkTheDOM(document.body);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="first-level-1">
    <div id="second-level-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="first-level-2"></div>
  <div id="first-level-3"></div>
</div>
```